Class-like behavior in C?
I'm writing a basic space-invaders-like program.  I have the invaders setup as an array of structs, where each element has: the type of invader, the status (alive or dead), and the X and Y coordinates.
I'm currently working on moving the invaders across/down the screen.  It seems unnecessary to loop through the array to update each X and Y, since all invaders in the same column have the same X and all invaders in the same row have the same Y.  It seems like I should be able to update a separate variable (or two) and have each of the invaders inherit (or whatever) the appropriate offset.
Is there a decent way to do this in C (not C++)?

There's no class as a language concept, but you can simulate it yourself by creating structs to storage data, and using them with method-like functions that take the "object" as their first parameter. However, this is pretty much unrelated to how you would store coordinates. At the end of the day, they're some x/y values in a struct somewhere.

"It seems like I should be able to update a separate variable (or two)" This is a premature optimization. Just give each invader its own x and y coordinates, and update them all on each game tick. It'll be near-instant on modern hardware.

@Alexander It's on a microcontroller, which is why I would like to optimize.

Please edit your question and post the code that you do have. But, I'm not sure what you mean by "class-like behavior" in this context. Unless you want to remove x and y from your struct somehow, I don't see a way around it. Even if you did move x and y to (e.g.) struct position { int x; int y; }, you'd still have to loop through an array. For an example of class-like/inheritance in C, see my answer: Writing a 'generic' struct-print method in C

Write the program in a simple and straightforward manner (at first). A maxim: Make it right before you make it faster ("Elements of Programming Style" by Kernighan/Plauger). Then, add benchmarking. Prove that the simple method is too slow. Then, optimize the parts that are the true bottlenecks.

@CraigEstey The class-like behavior is that the elements share properties, as I mentioned in my question (2nd para, 2nd sent).

If each invader has it's own x/y then you HAVE TO update each invader individually. There are alternatives though. If the x/y is the invaders "offset" from the "home" position (lets say the top left) then the offsets never change, just the home position moves - to the left then down and to the right then down and to the left... You add the invader's x/y to home to figure out the position. Other more complex options would be individual row and column collections instead of just an array.

In general, I don't see why you'd think classes make anything more efficient. It's all the same assembly instructions, so any logic you could do with classes you could also do without them. That includes things like relative offsets -- I literally don't understand why you think OOP makes that easier.

Linux kernel drivers use OOP in C a lot: Object oriented programming in C, How would one write object-oriented code in C?, Object Oriented pattern in C?, How do you do inheritance in a non-OO language?

Having a 1D array for X positions and one for Y isn't a bad idea.  I'd be updating 11 + 5 = 16 positions instead of 11 x 5 = 55.  And I could have the struct array elements link to the appropriate X and Y array elements.

@Mike This proposed optimization isn't necessarily an optimization. If the invaders "share" an offset, you might save on memory, but you might spend more time computing position+offset

@Alexander Unless I'm missing something...All invaders in, say, the first column have the same X position which would be the first element in the Xpos array.  And then similar for the other columns and rows.  I wouldn't be computing anything, I don't think.

You don't need classes to have shared data. A pointer to the place your column's state is tracked and there you are.

My experience of writing simple computer games in C (snake, tetris etc) is that you store everything in a matrix and then refer to places in that matrix through external containers, like linked lists with static array allocation or otherwise just a pointer look-up table etc. That external container can have the class overhead. Since the raw data is stored in one big array and the overhead info in another, it's pretty cache-friendly. And only one thread accesses the graphics. Why people seem to think this is mutually exclusive with proper program design, I have no idea.

The key to performance is simply just to not call malloc all over the place, or to create threads in the middle of run-time etc etc.

Anyway on a modern PC that whole performance discussion is pretty meaningless since it will never be a problem unless one manages to write some seriously horrible code.

Given that you say:

It seems unnecessary to loop through the array to update each X and Y, since all invaders in the same column have the same X and all invaders in the same row have the same Y. It seems like I should be able to update a separate variable (or two) and have each of the invaders inherit (or whatever) the appropriate offset.

I'm assuming you're trying to move all invaders in sync and never break the inherent grid formation. In which case, OOP is not your answer, but leaning heavily on the monotonicity of the grid, such that you maintain only the position of the grid itself. This is sort of a spin on John Bayko's answer, but without maintaining the coordinates of each invader directly.
You essentially end up wanting to do something like (Python-ish pseudocode):
GRID_WIDTH = 8
for i in range(0,INVADERS_COUNT):
    column = i % GRID_WIDTH
    row = i / GRID_WIDTH
    if not invaderDead(column, row):
        drawInvader(invaderType, GRID_X + (column * FIELD_WIDTH), GRID_Y + (row * FIELD_HEIGHT) )

That way:

You only have to maintain the top left corner of the grid in memory
Each invader will be drawn in a FIELD_WIDTHxFIELD_HEIGHT square of the grid
invaderType is basically just to cover maybe the sprite of the invader, but you can also compute that based on column/row if you want.

And then the only other thing you have to worry about is indicating when an invader has been destroyed, which there are any number of ways to do but you might be able to get away with an array of bitfields (in this example, row would even provide you which array item to modify and column would give you the shift offset, assuming INVADERS_COUNT is like 64)

All invaders must have a different X and Y to differentiate their position when rendering. When rendering, you need to visit each invader anyway, update the values then.
If you just want to save memory, keep track of the relative positions, as in a linked grid (linked lists per column that go vertical, lists per row that go horizontal, and share elements) and compute the X and Y (no X and Y storage needed). You need dummy elements in empty spaces to get the offsets right. I think the linked lists might take more memory than just storing X and Y, using an array might help if you don't mind wasting array entries for deleted invaders.
You'll still need one global X and Y for the start position, and compute from there. If you don't mind storing X and Y for each invader (maybe 1D array or linked list), but you just don't want to increment each one, increment the global X and Y, and compute individual positions by adding global X + invader X (same for Y).
Anyway, none of these involve classes. Classes wouldn't have solved your initial problem anyway - you're not inheriting anything, and inheritance would just add the inherited fields to each object anyway, just declaring the same X and Y field with different syntax.

The only risk there is by introducing another data structure instead of simple loops, the compiler may not be able to optimize that as well on its own as it could optimize simple loops. That depends on the compiler .... which bring us back full-circle to the comment by @CraigEstley under the original question. That said, you idea is good.

After watching video of the original arcade versions I realized that the invaders don't, in fact, move completely in unison with each other...There is a lag, mostly likely due to what the hardware was capable of doing at that time.  So yeah, I'll be going with separate X and Y coords for each.

@Mike In the original game? Yes, that's also why the game sped up as you advanced.
